# Is it possible to create this background effect using CSS3 and Compass?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm working to apply a comp provided by our designer to a website.

The effect I need to create for the background is the folowing:

[image]

It has a radial in the centre AND a gradient from top to bottom

Is it possible to create this effect on one element using CSS3 and Compass or would I have to build it using two layers?

Can you recommend a better way of creating the same effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is possible with pure CSS, it is possible with Sass/Compass.  In fact, it wouldn't look a whole lot different than how you would write it with pure CSS:

```
.foo {
  @include background(radial-gradient(blue, transparent 10em), linear-gradient(black, white));
}
```

You'll need to adjust the radial-gradient to match your image, of course, but it can be done.

Comment: Wow! Thanks - that's nearly perfect! How can I move the radial so that 50% of it is off the top of the page?

Comment: You'll need to lookup the radial-gradient properties, but it can be done:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient.  If all else fails, you can always use a background image instead of the radial-gradient.

Comment: `@include background(radial-gradient(50% -15em, #4c6375, transparent 30em), linear-gradient($bgGray, transparent));
`