# How can I set UITableView's section's header gradient (and transparent) background in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I tried it in several ways, but I cannot make it unfortunately. The best so far was this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574916/how-could-i-set-gradient-fixed-background-on-uicollectionview/45362646#45362646).

I think the solution should be in the function `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)`, but I don't have any idea how to do that.

I would like to get something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189821/is-it-possible-to-create-this-background-effect-using-css3-and-compass). I use Swift 5+ and the target iOS can be anything (13+).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Use ViewForHeaderInSection as below:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = self.getGradientBackgroundView()

    // Add any title to the Header if needed
    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRect.init(x: 5, y: 5, width: headerView.frame.width-10, height: headerView.frame.height-10)
    label.text = "My header"
    headerView.addSubview(label)

    return headerView
}
```

**2. Set Height of the header using heightForHeaderInSection:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50 //whatever height you needed.
    }
```

**3. To get the gradient BG Header View**

```
  private func getGradientBackgroundView() -> UIView {
    let gradientBackgroundView = UIView()

    // Prepare Gradient Layer
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.myTableView.frame.size.width, height: 50) // height same as in heightForHeaderInSection
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]
    // Add layer to view
    gradientBackgroundView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    return gradientBackgroundView
  }
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Unfortunately after I added this code, the whole tableView becomes this greenish color.

Comment: You have to change the colors based on ur needs in the below line:
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]

Comment: The color doesn't matter at this point. Here is what I see: https://prnt.sc/r1xpyv . This is in the whole tableview (as you can see, I scrolled approx. to the half of the tableview to be sure, that I cannot see any cells).

Comment: I couldn't load the page, can you attach it here for visibility?

Comment: @jasond - oops the size is incorrect!!!! 
Check my updated answer, just modified the gradientLayer.frame.size value. check and let me know

Comment: Thanks, that works! I need to put the title of the section in the willDisplayHeaderView function. But finally it works.